# Получение имен всех файлов из Firebase Storage

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, storage

Возможно ли получить все названия/ссылки файлов в ArrayList из Firebase Storage, зная путь, но не зная имени файла и их количество? Если возможно, то как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На момент ответа - в API Cloud Storage нет возможности получить список файлов из какой-либо папки. Это связано с изначальными ограничениями безопасности.
Самый быстрый способ на мой взгляд хранить ссылки на файлы в любом месте, и уже по ним делать запросы, например в БД

```
    String photoPath = db.getPhotoPath();
    StorageReference storageRef = firebaseStorage.getReference();
    StorageReference photoRef = storageRef.child(photoPath);
    photoRef.getBytes...
```

Очень странно что для такого вида API нет пока такой возможности, существуют ещё несколько воркэраундов для получения нужных ссылок, например именовать с общим тегом, или класть файл в корне (JSON) и уже его поддерживать и тд. Надеемся что появится.